# Need to merge into a single record per group, and the data is merged in such a way that we have the most complete set of attributes

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT a.*
FROM MRSVoid.dbo.Customer_Dataset$ a
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 
[Customer_LastName]
,[Customer_FirstName]
,[Customer_AddressLine1]

,[Customer_HomePhone]
,[Customer_InternetEmail]
FROM MRSVoid.dbo.Customer_Dataset$ 
GROUP BY [Customer_LastName],
[Customer_FirstName],
[Customer_AddressLine1],
[Customer_InternetEmail],
[Customer_HomePhone]
HAVING count(*) > 1) b
where ((a.Customer_LastName = b.Customer_LastName) OR (a.Customer_LastName is NULL AND b.Customer_LastName is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_FirstName = b.Customer_FirstName) OR (a.Customer_FirstName is NULL AND b.Customer_FirstName is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_AddressLine1 = b.Customer_AddressLine1) OR (a.Customer_AddressLine1 is NULL AND b.Customer_AddressLine1 is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_InternetEmail = b.Customer_InternetEmail) OR (a.Customer_InternetEmail is NULL AND b.Customer_InternetEmail is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_HomePhone = b.Customer_HomePhone) OR (a.Customer_HomePhone is NULL AND b.Customer_HomePhone is NULL))
order by Customer_AddressLine1
```

This query gives me duplicate rows from a dataset, now I need to merge into a single record per group, and the data merged in such a way that we have the most complete set of attributes as possible. Example:
a. If two duplicate records share an email address, but only one has a full mailing address, the resultant merged record should have both the email and the mailing address.
b. If two duplicate records have different values for one of the following, the merged record should use the more recent attribute as identified by the ModifiedOn and/or CreatedOn timestamp values.

Sample data

```
ID  CreatedOn   ModifiedOn  Customer_LastName   Customer_FirstName  Customer_AddressLine1   Customer_City Customer_State    Customer_Zip    Customer_HomePhone  Customer_InternetEmail
27196   2012-11-14 18:51:07.000 2012-11-17 15:28:45.000 NULL    David   98 Pelmor Dr    Marmora OR  85044   NULL NULL
14983   2012-11-18 14:02:44.000 2012-11-18 14:02:44.000 NULL    David   98 Pelmor Dr    Marmora OR  85044   NULL NULL
```

Comment: @DaleBurrell tsql

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @DaleBurrell SQL SMS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` window function

```
with cte as
(
SELECT a.*
FROM MRSVoid.dbo.Customer_Dataset$ a
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 
[Customer_LastName]
,[Customer_FirstName]
,[Customer_AddressLine1]

,[Customer_HomePhone]
,[Customer_InternetEmail]
FROM MRSVoid.dbo.Customer_Dataset$ 
GROUP BY [Customer_LastName],
[Customer_FirstName],
[Customer_AddressLine1],
[Customer_InternetEmail],
[Customer_HomePhone]
HAVING count(*) > 1) b
where ((a.Customer_LastName = b.Customer_LastName) OR (a.Customer_LastName is NULL AND b.Customer_LastName is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_FirstName = b.Customer_FirstName) OR (a.Customer_FirstName is NULL AND b.Customer_FirstName is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_AddressLine1 = b.Customer_AddressLine1) OR (a.Customer_AddressLine1 is NULL AND b.Customer_AddressLine1 is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_InternetEmail = b.Customer_InternetEmail) OR (a.Customer_InternetEmail is NULL AND b.Customer_InternetEmail is NULL))
AND ((a.Customer_HomePhone = b.Customer_HomePhone) OR (a.Customer_HomePhone is NULL AND b.Customer_HomePhone is NULL))
)

select * from 
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by Customer_LastName,Customer_FirstName,  Customer_AddressLine1 order by ModifiedOn desc) as rn from cte
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: I am getting null values as well, I want to avoid that and have the row which has a merged of all the other values.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, more like an idea:

```
SELECT t.CustomerName, q1.Email, q2.MailingAddress
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerName
    FROM Customers
    GROUP BY CustomerName
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 c1.Email
    FROM Customers c1
    WHERE c1.CustomerName=t.CustomerName
    AND c1.Email IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY ISNULL(ModifiedOn,CreatedOn) DESC
) q1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 c1.MailingAddress
    FROM Customers c1
    WHERE c1.CustomerName=t.CustomerName
    AND c1.MailingAddress IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY ISNULL(ModifiedOn,CreatedOn) DESC
) q2
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge records of multiple rows based on a `GROUP`, you should be doing like following.

```
SELECT   Max(id) as Id, 
         Max(createdon) as createdon, 
         Max(modifiedon) as  modifiedon
         --OTHER COLUMN USING MAX
FROM     ( 
                --YOUR CURRENT QUERY
                SELECT <YOUR SELECT HERE> 
                FROM  ....
    ) t 
GROUP BY <ColumnNameOnWhichYouWantToGroup>
```

Above query will covert multiple rows to one row with a `GROUP BY`. The correct values are taken using the aggregate function `MAX`.

Comment: I am getting null values with the rows as well. Like :-
Customer_FirstName Customer_AddressLine1 Customer_City modifCustomer_Stateiedon Customer_Zip Customer_HomePhone Customer_InternetEmail
David NULL Princeton Junction OR 04062 NULL NULL
David 21 Zoye Dr Dalton OR 07885 268-417-7691 NULL
David 33 Blio Radgo Rd Plymouth OR 19054 268-292-7165 jermond@bbhartford.com

Comment: I am not sure if i understand , can you elaborate, how do you want the null should work?

Comment: The query I mentioned above is to find the duplicate values from the original dataset, it also has null values like - last name and all other fields as NULL. With this query I want to have 1 entry as per the given conditions.
For Eg : If my above query has returned 3 rows for David, first with all null, 2nd with all fields and 3rd fields with other unique values. I want to have 1 column without the row of NULL values.

Comment: In that case this approach should work, if both the rows have null and if you aggregate it using MAX, you will get null only in the single row.

Comment: But then it doesn't satisfy the original conditions.
 If two duplicate records share an email address, but only one has a full mailing address, the resultant merged record should have both the email and the mailing address. b. If two duplicate records have different values for one of the following, the merged record should use the more recent attribute as identified by the ModifiedOn and/or CreatedOn timestamp values.